# Answers without owners

Tags: support, api, data-dump

Is it valid for Stack Overflow data to have an answer that does not have an owner?

For example if you hit the following API url http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/answers/18, it does not bring back an owner. If I look at the quarterly data dump, the OwnerUserId field is null.

However if I go to the website and hit the question page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql) I see a user (PHPGuy) who answered the question, but does not have a hyperlink for that user.

Would this be a user who no longer is part of Stack Overflow or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the user is no longer an active member of Stack Overflow. You can find more information [on this page in the API docs](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage/returned-fields):

> This affects "shallow user" fields most frequently.
>   For example, [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/what-are-the-dark-corners-of-vim-your-mom-never-told-you-about) owner has been deleted (a very rare occurrence). An [API query](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/726894) for that question returns no user accordingly.